# how to check if schema.field.dataype is array of strings in scala with spark

Tags: arrays, string, scala, apache-spark

This is source code :

```scala
override def createWriter(writeUUID: String, schema: StructType,
                            saveMode: SaveMode, options: DataSourceOptions): Optional[DataSourceWriter] = {
    saveMode match {
      case SaveMode.Append =>
        schema.fields.foreach(field => {
          if (field.dataType.typeName == "array") {

            throw ArrayDataTypeNotSupportedException(s"${field.name} column is ArrayType, " +
              "writing arrays to CSV isn't supported. Please convert this column to a different data type.")

          }
        })

        val sparkSession = SparkSession.active
        val hadoopConf = new SerializableConfiguration(sparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)

        val optionsMap = options.asMap()
        val csvOptionsMap = optionsMap.asScala.toMap // convert Java HashMap to Scala Map
        // needed for the UnivocityGenerator
        val csvOptions = new CSVOptions(
          csvOptionsMap,
          columnPruning = sparkSession.sessionState.conf.csvColumnPruning,
          sparkSession.sessionState.conf.sessionLocalTimeZone)


        Optional.of(new KinesisCSVDataSourceWriter(writeUUID, KinesisCSVDataSourceOptions(csvOptionsMap, schema), csvOptions, hadoopConf))

      case _ => throw UnsupportedSaveModeException("Only SaveMode.Append is supported")
    }
  }
}
```

and test case is :

```scala
test("testArrayInSchema") {
    val df = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
      TestDataSetArrays(
        Array(1, 2, 3),
        Array("a", "b", "c"),
        Array(new Timestamp(0), new Timestamp(1), new Timestamp(3))
      )
    ))

    assertThrows[ArrayDataTypeNotSupportedException] {
      writeDataFrame(df)
    }
  }
```

Please help how can I check the schema.filed.datatype is a string of array not only array.

Previously array was not supported but now I want to support an array of strings only and String array should be converted to a comma-separated String.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this-

```scala
 val df = spark.sql("select array('a', 'b') as arr")
    df.printSchema()
    /**
      * root
      * |-- arr: array (nullable = false)
      * |    |-- element: string (containsNull = false)
      */

    val arr = df.schema("arr")
    println(arr.dataType.isInstanceOf[ArrayType]
      && arr.dataType.asInstanceOf[ArrayType].elementType == StringType )

    /**
      * true
      */
```

you can also use match expressions if you wanted to check for all fields-

```scala
 df.schema.fields.foreach(f => f.dataType match {
      case arrayType: ArrayType if arrayType.elementType == StringType => println(s"field $f is of type array<String>")
      case _ => println(s"field $f is of type ${f.dataType}")
    }
    )

    /**
      * field StructField(arr,ArrayType(StringType,false),false) is of type array<String>
      */
```

### Update based on comments

**converting `array<string>` to `comma saperated string`**

```scala
 val cols = df.schema.map(f => f.dataType match {
      case arrayType: ArrayType if arrayType.elementType == StringType =>
        // convert array<string> to string
        concat_ws(",", col(f.name)).as(f.name)
      case _ => col(f.name)
    })
    df.select(cols: _*)
      .show(false)
    /**
      * +---+
      * |arr|
      * +---+
      * |a,b|
      * +---+
      */
```

Comment: It is a test so I would go with `fail("message")` rather than `println("message")`

Comment: Its just to show that `case` is working. the `print` expression can be replaced with anything like `String array should be converted to a comma-separated String.`

Comment: @Someshwar Kale Thanks for the comment will try this and check. Can you please help me how above String array will be converted to a comma separated String.

Comment: for e.g. |ID|ArrayOfString|Age|Gender|
+--+-------------+---+------+
|1 | [A,B,D]     |22 | F    |
|2 | [A,Y]       |42 | M    |
|3 | [X]         |60 | F    |
+--+-------------+---+------+

I want array of string seprated by commas pls help me with code which I can write just below of the code which you gave me above @someshwar kale

Comment: @Someshwar Kale thank you very much. Let me try above updated one.

Comment: @somnath kale I updated my code as below :
saveMode match {
      case SaveMode.Append =>
        schema.fields.foreach(f =>
          f.dataType match {
            case arrayType: ArrayType if arrayType.elementType == StringType =>
              // convert array<string> to string
              concat_ws(",", col(f.name)).as(f.name)
            case _ => col(f.name)

          }
        )

Comment: but I still want the 
throw ArrayDataTypeNotSupportedException(s"${field.name} column is ArrayType, " +
              "writing arrays to CSV isn't supported. Please convert this column to a different data type.")

if there is array of other dataype if string of array is not there .... so goal is if string array is there then explode values separeted by comma if apart from string array other type of array is there then throw array not accepted exception ..

Comment: @Someshwar Kale

Comment: that should be easy, no? add other cases then as `case arrayType: ArrayType if arrayType.elementType != StringType =>`

Comment: yes, did same like below:
case arrayType: ArrayType if arrayType.elementType != StringType =>
              throw ArrayDataTypeNotSupportedException(s"${f.name} column is ArrayType, " +
             "writing arrays to CSV isn't supported. Please convert this column to a different data type.")

            case _ => print("array not supported") but did not work